# Flutter how to make bottomnavigationbar constant when moving from one activity to another

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have a page with bottomnavigationbar that route to 3 different pages on click on each icon. My code runs fine but I want the bottomnavigation to stick when routing from one page to another. Below is my code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  
  int currentTab = 0; 
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    DealActivity(),
    FinalLoginPage(),
    ProfilePageUsers(),
  ];
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();


 Widget currentScreen = DealActivity(); // Our first view in viewport

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const assetHome = 'assets/home_off.svg';
    const assetRedemptions = 'assets/redeemed_off.svg';
    const assetProfile = 'assets/profile_off.svg';


    const assetHome1 = 'assets/home_on.svg';
    const assetRedemptions1 = 'assets/redeemed_on.svg';
    const assetProfile1 = 'assets/profile_on.svg';


    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      body: PageStorage(
        child: currentScreen,
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: colorGreen,
        child: Container(
          height: 45,
          child: Row(

            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                minWidth: 5,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentScreen = DealActivity();
                    ; // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                    currentTab = 0;
                  });
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                      child: currentTab == 0 ? SvgPicture.asset(assetHome1,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                          semanticsLabel: 'Home'):SvgPicture.asset(assetHome,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                          semanticsLabel: 'Home'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              MaterialButton(
                minWidth: 5,
                onPressed: () async{
                  setState(()  {
                    currentScreen =_email == "" ?RedemptionPage():FinalLoginPage(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                    currentTab = 2;

                  });

                  SharedPreferences prefs =
                  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                  prefs.setInt('currentTab', currentTab);
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                      child: currentTab == 2 ? SvgPicture.asset(assetRedemptions1,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                          semanticsLabel: 'Redemptions'):SvgPicture.asset(assetRedemptions,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                          semanticsLabel: 'Redemptions'),
                    ),
                     ],
                ),
              ),

              MaterialButton(
                minWidth: 5,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentScreen = _email == ""
                        ? ProfilePage()
                        : ProfilePageUsers(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                    currentTab = 3;
                  });
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                      child: currentTab == 3 ? SvgPicture.asset(assetProfile1,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                          semanticsLabel: 'Profile'):SvgPicture.asset(assetProfile,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                          semanticsLabel: 'Profile'),
                    ),
                    ],
                ),
              ),



            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For instance, if I click on DealActivity() and from DealActivity I move to another page, I want the bottom navigation to stick to the bottom and still shows DealActivity Icon active as I move from one page to another in DealActivity. Also, if am in FinalLoginPage() and within I move to another page the bottom navigation should stick with it icon active. The same should go for ProfilePageUsers(). I really will appreciate any help to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar 
In working demo you can see each screen has it own route and icon is active when navigate

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Persistent Bottom Navigation Bar example project',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MainMenu(),
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
  }
}

class MainMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  MainMenu({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainMenuState createState() => _MainMenuState();
}

class _MainMenuState extends State<MainMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Sample Project"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Custom widget example"),
              onPressed: () => pushNewScreen(
                context,
                screen: CustomWidgetExample(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Built-in styles example"),
              onPressed: () => pushNewScreen(
                context,
                screen: ProvidedStylesExample(
                  menuScreenContext: context,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ----------------------------------------- Provided Style ----------------------------------------- //

class ProvidedStylesExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext menuScreenContext;
  ProvidedStylesExample({Key key, this.menuScreenContext}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProvidedStylesExampleState createState() => _ProvidedStylesExampleState();
}

class _ProvidedStylesExampleState extends State<ProvidedStylesExample> {
  PersistentTabController _controller;
  bool _hideNavBar;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    _hideNavBar = false;
  }

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: "Home",
        activeColor: Colors.blue,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        title: ("Search"),
        activeColor: Colors.teal,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        title: ("Add"),
        activeColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
        activeContentColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.message),
        title: ("Messages"),
        activeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
        title: ("Settings"),
        activeColor: Colors.indigo,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Navigation Bar Demo')),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text('This is the Drawer'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: PersistentTabView(
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _buildScreens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        stateManagement: true,
        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
        hideNavigationBar: _hideNavBar,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.once,
        bottomScreenMargin: 0.0,
        // onWillPop: () async {
        //   await showDialog(
        //     context: context,
        //     useSafeArea: true,
        //     builder: (context) => Container(
        //       height: 50.0,
        //       width: 50.0,
        //       color: Colors.white,
        //       child: RaisedButton(
        //         child: Text("Close"),
        //         onPressed: () {
        //           Navigator.pop(context);
        //         },
        //       ),
        //     ),
        //   );
        //   return false;
        // },
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
            colorBehindNavBar: Colors.indigo,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
        popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
        itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          curve: Curves.ease,
        ),
        screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
          animateTabTransition: true,
          curve: Curves.ease,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        ),
        navBarStyle:
            NavBarStyle.style15, // Choose the nav bar style with this property
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ----------------------------------------- Custom Style ----------------------------------------- //

class CustomNavBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selectedIndex;
  final List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> items;
  final ValueChanged<int> onItemSelected;

  CustomNavBarWidget({
    Key key,
    this.selectedIndex,
    @required this.items,
    this.onItemSelected,
  });

  Widget _buildItem(PersistentBottomNavBarItem item, bool isSelected) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: IconTheme(
              data: IconThemeData(
                  size: 26.0,
                  color: isSelected
                      ? (item.activeContentColor == null
                          ? item.activeColor
                          : item.activeContentColor)
                      : item.inactiveColor == null
                          ? item.activeColor
                          : item.inactiveColor),
              child: item.icon,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
            child: Material(
              type: MaterialType.transparency,
              child: FittedBox(
                  child: Text(
                item.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: isSelected
                        ? (item.activeContentColor == null
                            ? item.activeColor
                            : item.activeContentColor)
                        : item.inactiveColor,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: item.titleFontSize),
              )),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: items.map((item) {
            var index = items.indexOf(item);
            return Flexible(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  this.onItemSelected(index);
                },
                child: _buildItem(item, selectedIndex == index),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomWidgetExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext menuScreenContext;
  CustomWidgetExample({Key key, this.menuScreenContext}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomWidgetExampleState createState() => _CustomWidgetExampleState();
}

class _CustomWidgetExampleState extends State<CustomWidgetExample> {
  PersistentTabController _controller;
  bool _hideNavBar;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    _hideNavBar = false;
  }

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: "Home",
        activeColor: Colors.blue,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        title: ("Search"),
        activeColor: Colors.teal,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        title: ("Add"),
        activeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
        title: ("Settings"),
        activeColor: Colors.indigo,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
        title: ("Settings"),
        activeColor: Colors.indigo,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Navigation Bar Demo')),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text('This is the Drawer'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: PersistentTabView(
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _buildScreens(),
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        itemCount: 5,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        stateManagement: true,
        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
        hideNavigationBar: _hideNavBar,
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
            colorBehindNavBar: Colors.indigo,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
        popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
        itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          curve: Curves.ease,
        ),
        screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
          animateTabTransition: true,
          curve: Curves.ease,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        ),
        customWidget: CustomNavBarWidget(
          items: _navBarsItems(),
          onItemSelected: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _controller.index = index; // THIS IS CRITICAL!! Don't miss it!
            });
          },
          selectedIndex: _controller.index,
        ),
        navBarStyle:
            NavBarStyle.custom, // Choose the nav bar style with this property
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final BuildContext menuScreenContext;
  final Function onScreenHideButtonPressed;
  final bool hideStatus;
  const MainScreen(
      {Key key,
      this.menuScreenContext,
      this.onScreenHideButtonPressed,
      this.hideStatus = false})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 20.0),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Test Text Field"),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: () {
                    pushNewScreenWithRouteSettings(context,
                        settings: RouteSettings(name: '/home'),
                        screen: MainScreen2(),
                        pageTransitionAnimation:
                            PageTransitionAnimation.scaleRotate);
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Go to Second Screen ->",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  onPressed: () {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      useRootNavigator: true,
                      builder: (context) => Center(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Text(
                            "Exit",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Push bottom sheet on TOP of Nav Bar",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  onPressed: () {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      useRootNavigator: false,
                      builder: (context) => Center(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Text(
                            "Exit",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Push bottom sheet BEHIND the Nav Bar",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.lime,
                  onPressed: () {
                    pushDynamicScreen(context,
                        screen: SampleModalScreen(), withNavBar: true);
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Push Dynamic/Modal Screen",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                  onPressed: () {
                    this.onScreenHideButtonPressed();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    this.hideStatus
                        ? "Unhide Navigation Bar"
                        : "Hide Navigation Bar",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(this.menuScreenContext).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "<- Main Menu",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 60.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.indigo,
                onPressed: () {
                  pushNewScreen(context, screen: MainScreen3());
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Go to Third Screen",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.indigo,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Go Back to First Screen",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen3({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text(
              "Go Back to Second Screen",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SampleModalScreen extends ModalRoute<void> {
  SampleModalScreen();

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 500);

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => false;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5);

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    // This makes sure that text and other content follows the material style
    return Material(
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      // make sure that the overlay content is not cut off
      child: SafeArea(
        child: _buildOverlayContent(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildOverlayContent(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "This is a modal screen",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 26.0,
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text(
                "Return",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I know of this persistence navigation bottom bar but I have the above code I posted work perfectly for me I just want a workaround to keep the bottom navigation bar when I navigate from one screen to another.